# Number of simultaneous VPN connections from office limited?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn

In our office we are several users (ca. 5) that regularly connect to a remote network via VPN. Usually this works fine and has worked fine for years, but recently we have had trouble when more than one or two people connect simultaneously. When an additional user connects, somebody's or everybody else's connection drops. The limit of users seems to vary, going from 1 to 4 maximum simultaneous connections.

The remote VPN host regularly has dozens of simultaneous connections from us as well as other partners. Their network specialists say that the problem must be on our side, since this has not been reported by any other partners.

We regularly connect do a dozen other networks via VPN without any trouble. This however is the only network that might have more than ca. 3 simultaneous connections from us.

We use the Cisco Systems VPN Client V.5.

Where should we start troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Is any NAT involved? NATs have a tendency to break many protocols. And certain VPN protocols can be problematic to get working through NAT. In some cases it works fine for a single connection but breaks as soon as you run two. This would not in itself explain why you can sometimes open more than one, but never more than four. However if the NAT has two external IPs, and if the VPN has two IPs, then there are four combinations, and it could work as long as there is no more than one connection for each of the four combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Stoney, your best bet is to work with the remote VPN host on this or hire a sysadmin consultant to help you out.  The issue is likely that they aren't allowing multiple connections from your WAN IP to create a client VPN tunnel or they are limiting a certain number of connections, but they should be able to troubleshoot it on their end easy enough to be honest.

Another easy enough test to verify this would be to test all 5 of you connecting from different WAN IPs...say 1 or 2 from the office, another from a cellular connection, someone else from home, etc.